# Jogo da velha em C. O programa se encerra antes

Tags: c, jogos

Estou tentando fazer um jogo da velha em linguagem em C porém na primeira jogada do jogador 1 dependendo onde colocar o 'X' o programa ja se encerra declarando o jogador um como vencedor. A seguir esta meu codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    int x, y, cont;
    char m[3][3], velha[3][3];
    for(x=0; x<3; x++){
        for(y=0; y<3; y++){
            m[x][y]='.';
        }

    }
    for(x=0; x<3; x++){
        for(y=0; y<3; y++){
            printf("%c\t", m[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



        while(cont<9){

        if(cont%2==0){
            printf("Jogador 1\n");
            printf("Digite qual a linha preencher ");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            printf("Digite qual coluna preencher");
            scanf("%d", &y);
            m[x][y]='X';
            velha[x][y]='X';

            if(velha[0][0]==velha[1][1] && velha[1][1]==velha[2][2]  || 
            velha[0][0]==velha[0][1]&& velha[0][1]==velha[0][2] || 
            velha[1][0]==velha[1][1] && velha[1][1]==velha[1][2] ||
             velha[2][0]==velha[2][1] && velha[2][1]==velha[2][2]||
         velha[0][0]==velha[1][0] && velha[1][0]==velha[2][0] || 
             velha[0][1]==velha[1][1] && velha[1][1]==velha[1][2] || 
            velha[0][2]==velha[1][2] && velha[1][2]==velha[2][2] || velha[0][2]==velha[1][1] && velha[1][1]==velha[3][0] ){
                printf("Jogador 1 venceu \n");
                cont=10;
            }



        }

            else if(cont%2!=0){
            printf("Jogador 2\n");
            printf("Digite qual linha preencher ");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            printf("Digite qual coluna preencher ");
            scanf("%d", &y);
            m[x][y]='0';
            velha[x][y]='0';
            if(velha[0][0]==velha[1][1] && velha[1][1]==velha[2][2]  || 
            velha[0][0]==velha[0][1]&& velha[0][1]==velha[0][2] || 
            velha[1][0]==velha[1][1] && velha[1][1]==velha[1][2] ||
             velha[2][0]==velha[2][1] && velha[2][1]==velha[2][2]||
         velha[0][0]==velha[1][0] && velha[1][0]==velha[2][0] || 
             velha[0][1]==velha[1][1] && velha[1][1]==velha[1][2] || 
            velha[0][2]==velha[1][2] && velha[1][2]==velha[2][2] || velha[0][2]==velha[1][1] && velha[1][1]==velha[3][0] ){
                printf("Jogador 2 venceu \n");
                cont=10;
            }
        }
        cont++;
        for(x=0; x<3; x++){
            for(y=0; y<3; y++){
            printf("%c\t", m[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
if(cont==9){
    printf("Nao teve vencedores ");

}












}
```

Comment: Você não inicia o valor de `cont` antes de chegar no `while`. Como você não iniciou esse valor, ele pode vir com qualquer lixo de memória. Faça `cont = 0` antes de chegar no laço

Comment: Outra coisa, na impressão do tabuleiro, dentro do `while`, ele vai imprimir a dimensão do `X` como linhas distintas, enquanto que o `Y` será as colunas. Normalmente é o contrário, se você tiver ciência desse comportamento e ele é desejado, está ótimo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variável cont não havia sido iniciada e seu `if` estava muito errado. Consertei para você, só copiar e colar. Recomendo também fazer uma função de checagem, para não ficar tão grande a condição.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void pedirechecar();
int main(){
    int x, y;
    int cont = 0;
    char m[3][3], velha[3][3];
    for(x=0; x<3; x++){
        for(y=0; y<3; y++){
            m[x][y]='.';
        }

    }
    for(x=0; x<3; x++){
        for(y=0; y<3; y++){
            printf("%c\t", m[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



        while(cont<9){

        if(cont%2==0){
            printf("Jogador 1\n");
            pedirechecar();
            m[x][y]='X';
            velha[x][y]='X';

            if((velha[0][0]=="X" && velha[1][1]=="X" && velha[2][2]=="X") || 
            (velha[0][0]=="X" && velha[0][1]=="X" && velha[0][2]=="X") || 
            (velha[1][0]=="X" && velha[1][1]=="X" && velha[1][2]=="X") ||
            (velha[2][0]=="X" && velha[2][1]=="X" && velha[2][2]=="X") ||
            (velha[0][0]=="X" && velha[1][0]=="X" && velha[2][0]=="X") || 
            (velha[0][1]=="X" && velha[1][1]=="X" && velha[1][2]=="X") || 
            (velha[0][2]=="X" && velha[1][2]=="X" && velha[2][2]=="X") || 
            (velha[0][2]=="X" && velha[1][1]=="X" && velha[3][0]=="X")){
                printf("Jogador 1 venceu \n");
                cont=10;
            }



        }

            else if(cont%2!=0){
            printf("Jogador 2\n");
            pedirechecar();
            m[x][y]='0';
            velha[x][y]='0';
         if((velha[0][0]=="X" && velha[1][1]=="X" && velha[2][2]=="X") || 
            (velha[0][0]=="X" && velha[0][1]=="X" && velha[0][2]=="X") || 
            (velha[1][0]=="X" && velha[1][1]=="X" && velha[1][2]=="X") ||
            (velha[2][0]=="X" && velha[2][1]=="X" && velha[2][2]=="X") ||
            (velha[0][0]=="X" && velha[1][0]=="X" && velha[2][0]=="X") || 
            (velha[0][1]=="X" && velha[1][1]=="X" && velha[1][2]=="X") || 
            (velha[0][2]=="X" && velha[1][2]=="X" && velha[2][2]=="X") || 
            (velha[0][2]=="X" && velha[1][1]=="X" && velha[3][0]=="X")){
                printf("Jogador 2 venceu \n");
                cont=10;
            }
        }
        cont++;
        for(x=0; x<3; x++){
            for(y=0; y<3; y++){
            printf("%c\t", m[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
if(cont==9){
    printf("Nao teve vencedores ");

}
}

void pedirechecar(){
    printf("Digite qual linha preencher ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Digite qual coluna preencher ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    if (velha[x][y] == "X")
    {
        printf ("Esse lugar já está marcado!");
        pedirechecar();
    }
}
```

Para verificar se já está preenchido você pode fazer um if dessa maneira:

```
if (velha[x][y] == "X")
{
    printf ("Esse lugar já está marcado!");
}
```

Comment: Deu certo!! Obrigado. Agr como q faço para verificar quando o jogador preenche algum espaço porem esse lugar ja esta preenchido?

Comment: Editei minha resposta com a solução para isso. Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta!

Comment: Mas se eu coloca assim, o jogador irá perder a jogada depois

Comment: Editei minha resposta, perceba a função `pedirechecar()`, não sei se vai funcionar bem, não conheço C muito bem.

Comment: Deu certo. Valeu